# How can i write this SQL?

Tags: sql, subquery

I have this SQL

```
SELECT url, urlnames,
COUNT(*) as urls
FROM table_url
WHERE urlnamegroup  = '(nourlgroups)'
GROUP BY url, urlnames,
ORDER BY url, urlnames,
```

But because of measurement errors, there is more than one urlnamegroup on the urls, like the urlnamegroup is (nourlgroups) and (urlgroup1). There are like 6 different urlnamegroups in my database.
How can i add that query into my url? Maybe with a subselect?

Comment: Remove final comma from GROUP BY and ORDER BY.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you, was a typo. :)

Comment: Have you tried to simply skip the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: I have to filter that because i have a programm who fixes the measurement errors with the info i get out of that sql.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images.) [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT url, urlnames,
COUNT(*) as urls
FROM table_url
WHERE urlnamegroup  IN ('(nourlgroups)', '(urlgroup1)', 'nexturlgroup')
GROUP BY url, urlnames
ORDER BY url, urlnames
```

You can use 'IN' clause to specify multiple search strings.

Comment: It has to be always (nourlgroups) and one of the other urlgroups.

Comment: I don't follow. The data is in the same column: urlnamegroup. What do you mean with it having to always be (nourlgroups) and one of the other? Do you mean that you have multiple columns for urlnamegroup?

Comment: Yeah exactly like that, there is more urlnamegroup columns when the url has more groups than one assigned to itself

Comment: I believe we need more information to be able to help you, such as sample data or at least a table definition.

Answer (score 0):

you can declare a variable and take the other URL value from the user(if thats the case the URL filter depends) than you can use it on where clause like ;
suppose you declare a nvarchar variable named @URLNAME, where clause;

where urlnamegroup  IN ('(nourlgroups)',@URLNAME)